# Changing base in radix sort

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, radix-sort

I learned about radix sort, but still can't figure something out.

Let's say that my max number is n<sup>c</sup> (c is constant). Can I always change the base of the numbers to be to n and so the worst case complexity will be O(n)?

And if so, isn't the best way to sort an array may be to find the max value O(n) and then use radix sort?

Comment: Complexity for radix sort would be O(size of array). The constant c factor determines the number of passes needed, but since it's a constant multiplier, it's ignored for the purposes of complexity, which remains as O(size of array).

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent questions here:

1. If the maximum value in the array is n<sup>c</sup> for a fixed constant c, then does radix sort in base n always take time O(n)?
2. What is the complexity of finding the largest value in an array and then using a base-n radix sort?

For question (1), you are correct that the runtime will be O(n). The cost of doing a radix sort is O(n log<sub>b</sub> U), where b is the base of the radix sort and U is the maximum value in the array (this is because that number has Θ(log<sub>b</sub> U) base-b digits in it). In this case, the runtime is therefore O(n log<sub>n</sub> n<sup>c</sup>) = O(nc) = O(n), assuming that c is a fixed constant.

Notice that the preceding analysis assumes that c is a *fixed constant known in advance*. If you're given an array of arbitrary integer values and use a base-n radix sort, then the runtime will be O(n log U / log n), which is only O(n) if you are guaranteed *in advance* that the maximum value is at most n<sup>c</sup> *for a fixed constant c*. Since this isn't in general a true statement, you can't say that radix sort always runs in time O(n).